# Localized app description does not appear on the App Store

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have a new iPhone app up on the App Store. This app has been fully localized into English and German. German is the native language of this app.

I added the English App Store description, added localized screenshots (and entered an English name for this app) in iTunes Connect ("Manage Localizations" - "Add Localization")

Unfortunately this translation does not appear on the App Store. Even in the UK and US App Store, there's always the German version of the app description.

This is not my first (localized) app which is available on the App Store ... but in this case, I have absolutely now idea what I'm doing (or what I did) wrong.

My app is called "ÖPNV-Navi" (the localized English title is "PT Guide"):
http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/opnv-navi/id455704043?mt=8 (UK Store)
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/opnv-navi/id455704043?mt=8 (US Store)
http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/opnv-navi/id455704043?mt=8 (German Store)

Any idea?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because your default language is German (This setting in iTunesConnect can NOT be changed once you submitted an App), if the iTunes can't find the localized description for the user's system language, it will display your default language instead.

As I've mentioned before, the language is not depend on the country of App Store but the user's system language settings, in my Mac which use English as its system language, I can see your English description in US Store. But in UK Store, since I am not using UK English as my system language, I got your default language: German.

If you change your Mac's system language into English, you will see your English description in US Store.

In addition, the most weird thing is the localized descriptions are bound to the specific country of App Store.

What dose this mean?

It means even you've created an English description in iTunes Connect, and the user do have English as his/her system language, but if he/she is NOT watching the US App Store, he/she will NOT get the English description but your default language, German.

What a confusing situation, what a "great" system, right?

Comment: You're right. I didn't notice these strange behaviors yet. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I also did not see the localized description in the app store.
The solution was that both the system language (in iOS or OS X) AND the **app store country** should be according to the language you want.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate content. If the questions are different, then please tailor your answer to the specific question asked. If the questions are the same, then flag one as a duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 0):

**Localize App Store information**

After you add an app to your account, you can add languages and enter localized information about your app that appears on the App Store. For a list of the languages and locales you can localize app metadata for, see App Store localizations. For the properties you can localize, see Required, localizable, and editable properties.

For example, if the primary language is set as English, the information in all App Store territories appears in English. If you add French to your app and localize the text, keywords, and screenshots, users whose language setting is French, see the French localization. Users who are located in a territory that includes French, but not English, as a supported language, also see the French localization. Users can also search for your app in all French-language App Stores using the localized keywords. In other App Store territories, users see the information in the primary language (English in this example).

The user’s language setting on the device controls which localization appears on the App Store. If there’s no localization available that matches the language, the next closest localization is used. If you want locale-specific metadata to appear, add a language for a specific locale to your app—for example, add French (Canada). The Apple Store URL for your app is the same, regardless of the user’s device language settings.

The languages you add to an app in iTunes Connect are not the same as the languages you add to your app in Xcode. The languages that you add in Xcode appear under Languages on the App Store. To localize your app binary, read Internationalization and Localization Guide.

**iTunes Connet help:**

en: https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/?lang=en#/deve6f78a8e2

中文: https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/?lang=cn#/deve6f78a8e2