# App Store description translation in non supported language

Tags: ios, app-store, translation

I've been tearing my hair out trying to understand how the translation systems works on App Store : 
I wanted to release my app to Poland and discovered that polish is not supported on the App Store. Fine ! Let's put some polish references, description and screenshot in my "english" default language while keeping the normal english in the "uk_english" non default language. 
(my app is not available in the US).

My app is now live and polish users see the non default "uk-english" description ...

According to : [Localized app description does not appear on the App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152033/localized-app-description-does-not-appear-on-the-app-store) I have settled every international parameters of my iPhone in polish, with a polish app store account, and I don't see the default "english" setting, but the non-default "uk english".

Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically there is no "default" language. Rather there is a list of languages in order of preference.

Since the UK is closer to Poland than the USA, it makes sense for UK english to be preferred over US english.

I would send an email to Apple asking how to deal with this situation.

Comment: I don't link this answer but thanks.
I already contacted Apple but they directed me to : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/iTunesConnectGuide where there is nothing written about that ...

Comment: @Diwann if you're not going to accept my answer you need to post your own answer and accept that. Every question should have an accepted answer.